# MPProcessors is deprecated in Mac OS 10.7. What's the alternative?

Tags: multithreading, macos, osx-lion

I am working on a fractal rendering app who's code dates back to 10.4. It uses NSThreads to manage rendering threads to calculate fractals.

Up until recently, it supported OSes back to 10.4, so I could not even upgrade it to use NSOperationQueues.

The app, FractalWorks, is now available in the Mac App store, who's minimum OS requirement is 10.6.6. Thus, we have abandonded support for older OSes, and will go back and rework the rendering to use NSOperationQueues or GCD.

In the meantime, I want to get it up and running cleanly in the newly released Lion. Specifically, I want to get rid of the long list calls that are newly deprecated in 10.7. This first pass will be a bare-bones upgrade.

The app currently uses the MPProcessors method to determine the number of cores on the system, so it can create a rendering thread for each core. It works fine, and MPProcessors even allows for hyperthreading on the i5/i7, and lets the program create double as many rendering threads as there are cores.

I need a modern call that will let me query the system for the number of logical cores, exactly as MPProcessors does now. The docs simply say that the method is deprecated, without offering an alternative. What IS the alternative? (And don't tell me GCD/NSOperationQueues. I know that's the way to go, but that is a bigger job than I am prepared to take on right now.)

Thanks in advance,

Duncan Champney
WareTo

Comment: So you know what the answer is, but you don't like it, so you're hoping for a different answer?

Comment: I know that you don't want to touch GCD or a technology like OpenCL, which might also be great for this, but I think you'll find that you can save a tremendous amount of code and improve performance by upgrading to those technologies.  I highly recommend that you watch Drew McCormack's [Concurrent Programming on Snow Leopard](http://ideveloper.tv/store/details?product_code=10001) video series, where he uses fractal calculations as an example of the power of these techniques.

Comment: Absolutely true in the long term, Caleb/Brad, but if I had a stable codebase already I'd be reluctant to rip it out too.

Answer (score 5):

In Cocoa: `[NSProcessInfo processInfo].processorCount`

In BSD-ese: `sysctlbyname("hw.ncpu", ...)`

With Gestalt: `Gestalt(gestaltCountOfCPUs, &count);`